# Unset duplicate data in a multi array and add that data into the first occurrence

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, unset, splice

I have an array that looks like this.

```
MainArray
(    
    [orderID] => array
    (
        [items] => array
        (
            [0] => array
            (
                [key] => value,
                [key] => value,
                [key] => value
            )
            [1] => array
            (
                [key] => value,
                [key] => value,
                [key] => value
            )
        ),
        [customer] => array
        (
            [key] => value,
            [key] => value,
            [key] => value,
        )
    ),
)
```

Trying to *idiotproof* our website, when a customer orders twice in a row instead of adding 2 items to his/her cart, the **MainArray** will have another **[orderID]** array added to it. Ideally every order that goes to the same person/address should be added to **[items]**. Otherwise we could end up sending 2 packages when it could have only been 1.

My question is how to compare all the **mainArray[orderID][customer]** data so that if there is a duplicate, I can unset that **[orderID]** and add the **[items]** of that array to the first occurrence of **mainArray[ ][customer]**.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm working with PHP.

Comment: What language is it? PHP I assume

Comment: Yes, I deleted the tag because it was a maximum of 5.